Does it impact martial art fighters when they go to different countries for competitions?
For example, someone from Australia goes to Nepal for a Taekwondo match would it impact the fighter's skill due to the different altitude levels...

Please take the tour. If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please accept the answer.

Higher altitude does affect any sports player or fighter since it affects humans: the lower oxygen concentration means our aerobic capacity is lowered, ie. we tire faster. This means that especially "power players" who seek to overwhelm their opponent at the beginning of their match will have a much harder time at doing so since they run out of breath faster.
Warm, wet climate can be a challenge since it affects your body's thermal management, ie. since you need to sweat more but the air does not take up moisture as well in wet climate, your thermal energy surplus dissipates slower. Therefore, your systemic max output can overheat your body fast and you will probably not reach it. This is even more of a problem for martial arts with a gi (ever trained judo in Tokyo/Kyoto in mid-summer? )
Apart from that, stress during the journey and jetlag etc. generally impair concentration, which impairs reaction times, which means you will find it harder to defend against any form of attack.
That's why high-profile sportspeople will be there some days before the event starts to get used to the altitude, climate, timezone and so on. If there's some money behind it (like UFC, championship boxing, etc) they also include high-altitude training etc. to better their maxVO2 into their normal training cycles. Normal people and martial artists hardly have the means to adapt to high altitude or warm and wet climate in a meaningful way in time, though. They may, therefore, perform worse than usual under such conditions for said reasons, given they're not used to them from home.
I don't see how any of this is specific to martial arts, though, even if I tried to point at aspects specific (some) martial arts where possible.

Thanks for the help
